# What's the difference between a directional derivative and a derivation?

Tags: differential-geometry

I asked my uncle what a derivation is and and he wrote the following:

> Most calculus courses discuss directional derivatives and include geometric applications to surfaces of the form $G(x,y,z)=0$, e.g.  the ellipsoid S defined by $x^2+4y^2+3z^2-11=0$.
>
> Let $A$ be the plane that is tangent to $S$ at the point $P=(2,-1,1)$.
>   Then $N = \nabla(G)=(2x,8y,6z)=(4,-8,6)$ is  a vector in the direction that is normal to the surface at  $P$.   A point $X=(x,y,z)$ is in $A$ if and only if $X-P$ is perpendicular to  $N$. (You should try to visualize this, with $X-P$ corresponding to a directed arrow from $P$ to $X$).  In other words,  the equation of the tangent plane is $(X-P)N=0$. (Equivalently $(X-P)U=0$, where $U=\frac{X}{\|X\|}$ is a unit vector in the same direction.) More explicitly $(x-2,y+1,z-1)\cdot (4,-8,6)=4x-8y+6z-22=0$
>
> To relate this to derivations, consider  a curve $f(t)$ that passes through $P$, say  $f(1)=P$. Its tangent vector is $f'(1)$.  We can break $f'(1)$ into two components, with one component in the $N$ direction, and another component in the plane $A$. If the component in the $N$ direction is zero, i.e. the directional derivative $D_{N}(f)=f'(1)\cdot U=0$, then $f'(1)$ actually lies in the tangent plane.  (More precisely, $P+f'(1)$ lies in $A$).
>
> The derivation is the directional derivative.

I don't understand how this relates to the definition:

> A linear map $v: C^\infty (M) \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ is called a *derivation at p* if it satisfies 
>   \begin{equation}
> v(fg) = f(p)vg + g(p)vf 
> \end{equation}
>   for all $f,g \in C^\infty (M)$.

I feel like it would be foolish to conclude a derivation is a directional derivative. I doubt that's what he is saying.

**My Question Specifically:**

Can someone summarize why my uncle's example is a natural way to explain the definition at the bottom? I don't follow what his geometrical example has to do with derivations and the product rule. It didn't look like he even used it. I thought the product rule was like the defining feature of a derivation.

Comment: Derivations need not be at all related to derivatives in general. For example, the adjoint operator of an element of a Lie algebra is a derivation on the algebra.

Comment: just read about this in a differential geometry book, in particular equivalent definitions for tangent vectors

Answer (score 1):

Your uncle's explanation concerns mostly the tangent plane to a surface and the normal vector, rather than derivations.

The definition quoted afterwards is indeed the (algebraic) definition of derivation. However, there is a family of derivations which can be obtained geometrically by tangent vectors. Namely, if we have a manifold $M$, a point $p\in M$ and a tangent vector $v\in T_pM$, then the directional derivative along $v$,$$f\mapsto df(v),\quad f\in C^\infty(M),$$is a derivation.

Moreover, there are some conditions which can guarantee that these are all the derivations on $C^\infty(M)$. For example, this is the case if $M$ is smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold. Let $\mathcal{F}(p)$ be the set of (germs of) functions at a point $p\in M$. We define the *tangent space* of $M$ at point $p$ as the set of derivations of $\mathcal{F}(p)$. The set of derivations obviously forms a vector space. One may show that the set $\{\partial_i\}$ forms a basis of this vector space. Linear combinations $a^i\partial_i$ are elements of the tangent space and we call them *directional derivatives* in the direction of $a$. This is the connection between directional derivatives and derivations.

To be honest, I'm not sure how your uncle's example quite relates. As said by Yuval, that is more of an exercise in vector calculus/geometry.